# Running RMI client in Tomcat 7 got ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, tomcat, permissions, rmi, distributed-computing

I am having some difficulties with RMI and Tomcat. This is the big picture of this project I am working on: the RMI client is called by a Java servlet that runs in Tomcat, the servlet accept user input and pass the parameters to the RMI client. Then the RMI client then calls the RMI server to run the heavy compuation part. The problem is that although everything works fine without hosting the RMI client in the Tomcat server, it doesn't run once I put it in Tomcat.
Here are some configurations:
I DID NOT set up the security manager in the code, I assume that Tomcat will use its own.

```
    //if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
    //    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    //}
```

I also set the permission as following:

> $CATALINA_HOME/conf/catalina.policy

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/webapps/MyAPP/WEB-INF/classes/-" { 
    permission java.security.AllPermission "", ""; }; 
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/webapps/MyAPP/WEB-INF/lib/-" { 
    permission java.security.AllPermission "", ""; 
}; 
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/webapps/MyAPP/WEB-INF/lib/some-common-3.0.jar" { 
    permission java.io.FilePermission "*", "read, write"; 
};
```

Other than these two configurations, I didn't set any java.rmi.server.codebase or java.security.policy.

I got the following error by submitting the code from RMI client to RMI server:

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.SomeClass
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:334)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.executeTask(Unknown Source)
at cluster.server.centralservice.CentralManagementServer.submitJob(CentralManagementServer.java:232)
at cluster.server.centralservice.JobSubmitter.runJob(JobSubmitter.java:226)
at cluster.server.centralservice.JobSubmitter.doPost(JobSubmitter.java:144)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.SomeClass
```

I have been stuck here for a few days. Most examples I searched online is outdated and do not cover the RMI with Tomcat set up.
Can anybody help? Many thanks.

Comment: Is the RMI server running in the same JVM as Tomcat?

Comment: Thanks for the attenton. @EJP I assume the RMI server refers to the machine where I start the rmiregistry command. If that's the case, then the RMI server runs in a remote machine. The RMI that I run in Tomcat is the RMI client that calls the RMI server to run heavy computation on the RMI server. The RMI client is packaged in a jar and called by a servlet in Tomcat.

Comment: So mypackage.SomeClass isn't deployed to the server host in the CLASSPATH of the JVM from which the remote object was exported.

Comment: I think that's exactly the issue. But I don't know how to set the "java.rmi.server.codebase" through Tomcat. If I don't run this jar through Tomcat, I can just use System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase", "http://PATHTOJAR") and everything runs well. But once it's inside Tomcat, it seems Tomcat has its own way to handle things. Any suggestion?

Comment: You're not obliged to use the codebase feature. If you can deploy that class statically to the server JVM, do that. Otherwise you are going to have to figure out how to set that system property in Tomcat before your client exports any remote objects.

Comment: Thanks. @EJP I think I will have to figure out that. I will update this post once I get an answer from there.

Comment: Is the error occurring on the RMI server, or the RMI client (where Tomcat is running)? The stack trace looks like it's a server error, in which case setting the java.rmi.server.codebase property on the client isn't going to help. Instead, you need to find some way for the server to have access to the classes. The most straightforward way (not the only way) is to simply install all of the classes involved in the RMI transaction on both machines.

Comment: The error occurs at the RMI client where the Tomcat runs. @JesseBarnum I am trying to avoid a deployment that involves using shell script to copy jars around. It would be the best to ask the RMI infrastructure to take care of this itself to make it flexible.

Answer (score 0):

as the exception says

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.SomeClass
```

this happens coz RMI is using a seperate class loader which isn't able to see `SomeClass` .

Add `<Loader delegate="true"/>` into context.xml file (to Context element) in tomcat/conf directory.

This change fixed a similar issue I faced (not particularly with RMI) but worth a try.

Comment: thanks a lot. I just gave it a try. And I got the same result. Here is the context.xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource><Loader delegate="true"/></Context> Should I set a codebase in the code?